# How does bundler work (in general)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm pretty new to Ruby/Rails but I was taking a look at bundler and was wondering how it works exactly. Do you install a full set of gems like normal `gem install XYZ`and then use the Gemfile to pull a certain subset of those gems for use with a specific application? Or do you not install gems normally anymore and just include them in the Gemfile and then do a `bundle install` to include them all in a bundle that is then used with your application?

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer this, I'm just a little confused on what bundler's functionality is exactly.

-- MAP

Comment: check out http://gembundler.com/ if you haven't already. it's the official bundler site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of bundler as a package management tool.

From `bundle help` command:

`bundle install`          # Install the current environment to the system

`bundle package`          # Locks and then caches all of the gems into vendor/cache

So `bundle install` command will install all gems to the **system** that are listed in Gemfile as well as their dependencies. If the gem was not previously installed it will grab it from the gemcutter repo. `bundle package` will cache the .gem files into your **apps** vendor/cache directory.

No need to run `gem install` first.

Comment: I know we're not supposed to ask follow ups on on stackoverflow (according to the FAQ) but I have an extended question to this. What I'm really trying to do is manage multiple rails and ruby versions on one machine. So would I use RVM's gemsets for that and then use bundler as part of every RVM gemset I create in order to switch gemsets and with them rails versions?

Comment: I'm still not sure how it works -- how does it ensure you are running the proper version of a gem, for example, when there are more than one?

Comment: @Toybuilder You specify your Gem dependencies in a Gemfile. Bundler fully resolves your entire Gem dependency graph and freezes it in your app's Gemfile.lock. You can actually view the graph using `bundle viz`.

Answer (score 7):

These two links explain everything about bundler.

- [How does bundler bundle](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/9/24/how-does-bundler-bundle)
- [How does bundle require gems](http://kerdany.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/how-does-bundler-do-its-magic/)