# How does Bundle know what gems to install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

How does Bundle know what gems need to be installed when I do a "bundle install"? Does it look for gems in a specific directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058286/how-does-bundler-work-in-general

Comment: Voting not to close. This is not opinion-based. This question has one and only one right answer, and it has already been given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) looks for a your gem dependencies in the Gemfile at the root of your Rails project folder, and executes the command `bundle install`.