# can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (react-native pod install)

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods

I just start a react-native project. However, this question had me for a day.
I tried all possible way to solve it. For example,

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
rvm uninstall
brew install cocoapods
```

However, there is no luck for me.
I would like to point out that I can `pod --version` under other path but issue occur when I try to `pod` under my project path. I also tried to set rvm default version to 2.7.5 but issue still happen.
Also, I am not using Apple M1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /Users/nicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    3: from /Users/nicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    2: from /Users/nicholas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/nicholas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/nicholas/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

Answer (score 138):

Try running `bundle install` in the root of your project. Then either go to `ios` and run `pod install` or use `npx pod-install` from the project root.

Comment: Still having this issue with react-native: 0.70.1 and react 18

Comment: this worked for me, can anyone explain what `bundle install` does / is ?

Comment: If you don't have a Gemfile you can also try ` gem install cocoapods` instead of `bundle install`

Comment: The part I missed in my first attempt was "switch to project root, run `bundle install`". I ran in `/ios` and obviously it failed. I've been looking for this solution for two hours! Thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain what's happening with ``bundle install``

Comment: For M1 Mac try running `arch -arm64 bundle install`

Comment: `bundle install` command will install all gems to the system that are listed in Gemfile as well as their dependencies.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3058399/292927

Comment: `bundle install` , `gem install cocoapods` and `pod install` worked for me

Comment: if you used --skip-install flag when you were initiating your react native project, yes, do not forget to run bundle install before pod install.

Answer (score 26):

Remove cocoapods:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then instal again:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 14):

`bundle install` prior to `pod install` works.

When generating react native project the configuration is set to default mac gem version. If you have updated gem version on your mac the project configuration could not pick the correct gem version. thats why it throws the `can't find gem cocoapods`.

by doing `bundle install`, It will update the project config according to the mac gem version.

Comment: The command is case sensitive. Works when you type 'bundle install'.

Answer (score 13):

This issue is due to the difference in your default Ruby version and the Ruby version specified in your Gemfile. To **install multiple Ruby** versions you have to install **[rvm](https://nrogap.medium.com/install-rvm-in-macos-step-by-step-d3b3c236953b)** on your system and then install multiple Ruby versions. After installation of the ruby version specified in your Gemfile you have to run the `bundle install` command. [link](https://medium.com/@pk60905/bundle-install-and-bundle-update-80f3d6f52214)

> `bundle install` is a command we use to install the dependencies specified in your Gemfile.
> Simply put, Gemfile is a format for describing gem dependencies for Ruby programs. Or you can say it contains the gems you need in this project.

After this you can install run `npx pod-install` or `cd ios and pod install`.

Answer (score 4):

Install Brew

`curl -fsSL -o install.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh`

`/bin/bash install.sh`

`brew install chruby ruby-install`

`brew install cocoapods`

if you need to update cocoapods
`brew upgrade cocoapods`

`pod setup`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, cocoapods version was unavailable. So install available version by following code.

> sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4